# Git(hub) forking own repo - pull requests

Tags: git, github, version-control

So I have project1 which contains all of the code so that it itself can run correctly. Project2 uses the same codebase as project1 but with modifications, new features etc.

Given the 2 projects have slightly different goals, I work on them independently, but if theres some common code (like a bug fix) that is suitable in both projects, I will make the change in one, and make a pull request to the other. Otherwise, the 2 projects just act as if they're not aware of one another

How do I set up this type of workflow on github? I've read a number of threads/questions here about how to fork your own repo, but thats not my problem

So far, I have:

- Created a new blank repo (project2)
- cloned project2 to my machine
- Added a new upstream remote (project1)
- Pulled down the changes from upstream
- Pushed the code from project2 up to the project2 repo

In essence this gives me a full copy of project1, but in project2 repo. I can do the usual thing of committing and pushing to each repo independently so that solves half of my problems

Now, if theres something like a bug fix that needs to be committed and pushed to both, how do I do it?

When I go to project2 on github and click on pull requests, I can only see requests made from project2 branches, and project2 forks. I see nothing from project1. Likewise for when I check pull requests from project1.

the 2 projects cant see each other which makes it different from an actual fork (I think?), so how do I fix a bug and create pull requests from across these 2 repos?

Or is there a better/more appropriate way to handle 2 slightly different repos where you want to be able to make pull requests and merge in common changes for both projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The secret it to combine `git remote`, which lets your local git repo pull from 2 or more github repos, and `git cherry-pick`, which lets you re-apply a commit from elsewhere on the current branch.

Assuming you've already made the commit on project1, you might run:

```
cd ~/project1
git log

commit c947d3c40c2d479d6c79fa9894b352ac9210e5c5
Author: Brian Malehorn <>
Date:   Mon Jun 27 17:29:02 2016 -0700

    fixed the thing

cd ~/project2
git remote add project1 github.com/brian/project1
git fetch project1
git log project1/master

commit c947d3c40c2d479d6c79fa9894b352ac9210e5c5
Author: Brian Malehorn <>
Date:   Mon Jun 27 17:29:02 2016 -0700

    fixed the thing

git checkout -b fixed_the_thing
git cherry-pick c947d3c40c2d479d6c79fa9894b352ac9210e5c5
git push --set-upstream origin fixed_the_thing
```